# How to Search Multiple SOLR Core?

Tags: solr, multicore

In Single Solr Instance, multiple core(s) are there. No Shards, Replication and Cloud concept involved. Now how to search over multiple core in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search across cores, you'll have to use sharding. If the schema for both cores are identical, you can just query one core and provide the shards parameter.

If the schema is different, create a separate core that have a merged schema of both the target schemas, then query that core with the two separate cores as shards. Having FieldA, FieldB in core0 and FieldB, FieldC in core1 would require a schema with FieldA, FieldB, FieldC defined, and then a shards parameter that points to core0 and core1.

The primary issue with this approach is that if the documents are very different, scoring between them might be a bit weird, as comparing something from core0 with something from core1 can be strange.

Sharding also assumes that the documents are distributed evenly (as the scores are calculated locally on each core).

Comment: Just want to confirm one thing: lets say i have installed solr and created one simple core (say core 1) and then feed data to core 1 and next created another core (say core 2) and then feed data to core 2. And it is very simple means no shard and replication and solr cloud concept involved. Now according to you searching core1 and core2 altogether is not possible. Right?( I understood your last line that here diff core means dif kind of data and it does not make sense but still reconfirming it).

Comment: If they have _identical_ schemas, searching both can be done by saying that they're different shards (as manual sharding is just telling Solr "Both these belong to the same set of documents, please fetch information from both" - it's not something you have to enable or set up in the old, manual configuration). If they have different schemas, creating a super-schema and then asking for both the two other nodes as shards achieves the same.

Comment: I have understood but not fully. "creating a super-schema" - can you please make this thing a bit simple. say i have one shard and schema is having fieldA and field B and another shard is having a schema which contains field B and field C. So in that case you are saying that we need to create a super schema which will contain field A and field B and field C. If it is wrong then please correct me.
But now i didn't got what you have said "asking for both the two other nodes as shards achieves the same"? Please help me to understand this in the context of the above example i have said.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You'll need to have one common schema that defines FieldA, FieldB and FieldC, and a shards parameter that specifies both the other cores (FieldA, FieldB-core and FieldB, FieldC core). I'll edit my answer to be clearer.